# Unable to change the colour of pixel in UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, core-graphics

I got my problem solved already by using a different code. i just want to know what is wrong with the following one?

I wanted to change colour of every pixel in `UIImage` using bitmap data. My code is as follows:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIImage *image = self.imageViewMain.image;

    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;
    NSData *data        = (NSData *)CFBridgingRelease(CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef)));
    char *pixels        = (char *)[data bytes];

    // this is where we manipulate the individual pixels
    for(int i = 1; i < [data length]; i += 3)
    {
        int r = i;
        int g = i+1;
        int b = i+2;
        int a = i+3;

        pixels[r]   = 0; // eg. remove red
        pixels[g]   = pixels[g];
        pixels[b]   = pixels[b];
        pixels[a]   = pixels[a];
    }

    // create a new image from the modified pixel data
    size_t width                    = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    size_t height                   = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    size_t bitsPerComponent         = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef);
    size_t bitsPerPixel             = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(imageRef);
    size_t bytesPerRow              = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace      = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo         = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRef provider      = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, pixels, [data length], NULL);

    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGImageCreate (
                                            width,
                                            height,
                                            bitsPerComponent,
                                            bitsPerPixel,
                                            bytesPerRow,
                                            colorspace,
                                            bitmapInfo,
                                            provider,
                                            NULL,
                                            false,
                                            kCGRenderingIntentDefault
                                            );
    // the modified image
    UIImage *newImage   = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

    // cleanup
    free(pixels);
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
}
```

But when this code runs - I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` **error** shown like in the following image :

[image]

And here is some more information from debugging:

[image]

What is it that I'm missing or doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to mutate the array you get from `[data bytes]`

Comment: @dan : Ok, But why can't we, its just an array. not an NSArray object ?

Comment: It's an array that is backing an immutable object. It's also declared as `const`.  If you want to modify it use the `mutableBytes` method on `NSMutableData`

Comment: @dan : got it.. could you put an answer so that i can accept.

Answer (score 0):

try to alloc memory for pixels array like following code

```
char *pixels = (char *)malloc(data.length);
memcpy(pixels, [data bytes], data.length);
```

when pixels is not necessary, release this memory by call `free(pixels)`

Comment: some what helping but , gives me same error at this statement "pixels[a]   = pixels[a];" and the values are as follows : r = 3055613, g = 3055614, b = 3055615, a = 3055616

Comment: @anoXomus I don't know what algorithm you using but, it seem you did loop to out of memory. your data length may be 3055616. So in pixels content object from index 0 to 3055615, and when you access pixels[3055616] it will out off memory!

Comment: @anoXomus I think in your algorithm, you need to copy data from data bytes to pixels array. so you can use memcpy like I did edit answer